# How to resolve TFS DirectoryNotFoundException after implementing ordered test?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

We have a TFS 2013 server that runs our CI builds on every check-in, but we also have an overnight build that runs our entire suite of tests (some of them really expensive db tests) when no one's around.

That's all been running fine but I wanted to specify an order to the tests by using an Ordered Test.  So I put that in place and it appears to be running everything just fine with one exception: any test that wants to retrieve a file from disk by calling upon a relative path ends up in the following error.

> Test method TrackerTests.Accounting.ActionTests.AccountingActionFactoryTests.AccountingActionFactoryGeneratesCorrectActionsForSampleTestData threw exception: 
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Builds\3\Tracker2\Tracker Edge Nightly Test Run\TestResults\TFSBuild_T2BUILD2 2018-06-01 12_39_47\Out\Accounting\SourceData\Prepay-Cleared-12-16-2013-to-12-22-2013-schema.xml'.
>       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileSt

The fact that these tests all run fine when not in an Ordered Test container make me think that I simply need to tell it how to get to the right path.  The right path would be:

> C:\Builds\3\Tracker2\Tracker Edge Nightly Test Run\src_projects\Tracker2\TrackerEdge\TrackerTests\Accounting\SourceData\

But how/where do I do that?  I tried my hand at using a testSetting file, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Maybe you forget to set up the property "copy local=true" for a file/ an assembly or others, or you forget to call the settings file. Please check if this similar thread helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f3e8a6b-6236-41cf-9a9f-25041f0038cf/mstest-to-run-orderedtest-get-error-quot-systemiodirectorynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a?forum=vsunittest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up figuring out that the tests are sorted by namespace - at least at the top level.  This came after creating a .runsettings file and manipulating the ResultsDirectory element.  It affected where the build server goes to look for files, but the build server still wanted to add a couple of subfolder levels to it.

By throwing our most expensive db tests into their own namespace, I was able to manipulate the name of the namespace so that it sorted high on the list, and thus were performed early in the process, which was our goal.